# not able to apply jQuery mobile styling for dynamic data after ajax call

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div with data-role="content" .Initially I was parsing JSON and populating this div with the content and everything was working correctly.This div basically consists of collapsible set.As it was taking more time I thought of moving the entire html(copied from Chrome browser)under "content" div to an HTML file and use an ajax call and append it to "content" div .But unfortunately the collapsible tags inside collapsible set is not appearing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/HTMLPage1.htm")',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#content").html(result);
                $("#content").hide();
                $('#content').trigger("create");
            },
            complete: function() {
             $("#content").listview("refresh");
            }

        }); 
    });
```

Can anyone give me any idea why this is happening.
Thanks in advance.

With Best Regards,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: Try triggering the create method on the page, `$('#mypage').trigger('create');`

Comment: You may also want to include further example code. `$("#content").listview("refresh");` will only work on a list view that has already been created. You will want to use the create feature as was described in the other comment.

Comment: i tried all possibilites but it is not working..$('#content').trigger("create") is creating 1 more collapsible icon on expanding it i cant see the elements present under the collapsibleset. first level of the collapsible set is coming but on expanding nothing comes...m i missing something here

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or other working example?